# Android SDK tools older version (with working android tool)

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I've tried to install android SDK from official site. It include latest android SDK tools (version 25.3.1)
This package have utility `android` which is needed by my project (very big one); but this tool is no longer available:

> The android command is no longer available.
>   For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
>   For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager

According to [changelog](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html) it was discontinued in version 25.3.0 so I tried to check `sdkmanager` for older versions but unfortunately it only contains single version of tools.

How do I get an old version of android SDK with working `android` tool?

The official [site](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) has only latest version. Other links no longer work.

---

UPD.
Appium also [encountered](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/8017) this, they just fixed their tools to use the new setup.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912824/the-ant-folder-is-suddenly-missing-from-android-sdk-did-google-remove-it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Links described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27043655/3344612) still work:
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip - Mac OS X
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip - Windows
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip - Linux

Though it seems that google doesn't want older versions of SDK to be used by all means so this link may not last long.

Comment: This fixes a compile issue with Cocos2d-x as well (the cocos command line ant-based compiles use the `android` utility)

Comment: @Nulik I've added linux link