# WINDOWS: The "android" command is deprecated

Tags: android, cmd, environment-variables

**when i run the command 'android' in command prompt, i get the following:**

```
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat
and tools\bin\avdmanager.bat

**************************************************************************

Invalid or unsupported command 

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk
```

**I have included:** 
`D:\Development\Android\Sdk`
**to user variable - ANDROID_HOME** 
**and**
`D:\Development\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
`D:\Development\Android\Sdk\tools`
**to system variable PATH**

I cannot run the `android` command in the CMD terminal.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: If you need the old version see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049883/android-sdk-tools-older-version-with-working-android-tool If you wish to create a project without Android Studio see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47167769/295004

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem and for me it worked as soon as I downgraded the tools.

**To downgrade:**

SDK Tools Release Notes: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html
SDK Platform Tools Release Notes: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms.html

To download a manual version of SDK Tools, fill in the following url with a version from the above:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r-windows.zip
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r-macosx.zip

For me downgrading to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip worked just fine. Once you download an older version the tools, just rename the tools directory at your Android SDK install and replace with the downloaded version.

I didn't need to downgrade Platform Tools, but if you need to, here are those links as well:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r-windows.zip
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r-macosx.zip

Answer (score 0):

i also have this problem,

```
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
```

I would recommend to follow all the compoenent's exact version of the Document had stated

- Jdk 8
- Android 10 (Q)
- Android SDK Platform 29
- Intel x86 Atom_64 System
  Image or Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image
- Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2

Mine was jdk17 so i had to reinstall jdk8 and its work !!!

Comment: Glad reinstalling worked! Could you add a link to the documentation to your answer? That would help others who have the same problem!

Comment: which link do you need ?

if u need jdk8 its here : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html

also if my answer help can u upvote it <3