# qt 5.5 android Compile Error

Tags: android, qt

I've had some experience with Qt but none with android in Qt,
I've downloaded:

> Qt5.5-Android 
>   Jdk-1.8
>
> NDK-r14
>
> ant-1.10
>
> SDK r26

and I've given the appropriate addresses to the sections in Tools->Options->Android

However, When I create a brand new project, connect my phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 5, with USB Debugging ON) and select armeabi-v7a(GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.0), I get the following errors in compile time:

```
Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121" --ant C:/Users/Vahid/Downloads/Compressed/apache-ant-1.9.6-bin/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin/ant.bat
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
Generating Android Package
  Input file: C:/Users/Vahid/Documents/build-TestAndroid5-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0_c097e4-Debug/android-libTestAndroid5.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: C:/Users/Vahid/Documents/build-TestAndroid5-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0_c097e4-Debug/android-build/
  Application binary: C:/Users/Vahid/Documents/build-TestAndroid5-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_5_0_c097e4-Debug/libTestAndroid5.so
  Android build platform: android-25
  Install to device: No
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
00:43:15: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\5.5\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project TestAndroid5 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.5.0))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
```

I've been stuck in this for a couple of days now and I appreciate any suggestions, Thank you in advance.

Comment: it seams you are using ant, aren't you lately update android sdk? they removed ant scripts, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912824/ant-folder-missing-from-android-sdk/42921645#42921645

Comment: @V-master yes I'm using ant! wow! Downloading the old SDK now!

Comment: @V-master Thank you man! I was so frustrated over this! changing the SDK solved my problem!

Comment: if you would like to use ant build with newer SDK, you can always try some fixes like person in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398966/freshly-setup-qt-build-for-android-fails-on-osx-machine/43475894 just need to copy some files from older SDK's to newer one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to V-Master I changed my SDK to an older version.
Looks like that ant is removed from new android SDKs...