# Android : [exec] Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]

Tags: android, ant, google-project-tango, android-install-apk

I want to install an app on a Google Tango tablet, on which I'm root.
I tried as well to compile with `make -j` and `ant debug install`, I keep having the error `[exec] Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]` even if it ends with a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. The app doesn't install on the tablet.

I ran a logcat and here are (to me) the relevant catches :

```
I/PackageManager(  929): onServiceConnected
D/DefContainer( 3008): internal storage: block size=4096, # of available blocks=28501958
D/DefContainer( 3008): internal storage: availInternalSize=116744019968, apk size=4629092
W/ActivityManager(  929): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/superstuff-debug.apk
W/ActivityManager(  929): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/superstuff-debug.apk
I/PackageManager(  929): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl-1009153656
I/PackageManager(  929): Checking for more work or unbind...
I/PackageManager(  929): Posting delayed MCS_UNBIND
I/PackageManager(  929): Running dexopt on: fr.my.superstuff
I/dex2oat ( 3216): dex2oat: /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@fr.my.superstuff-1.apk@classes.dex
E/dex2oat ( 3216): Unrecognized version number in /data/app/fr.my.superstuff-1.apk: 0 3 8 
E/dex2oat ( 3216): Failed to open dex file '/data/app/fr.my.superstuff-1.apk' from memory
E/dex2oat ( 3216): Failed to open dex from file descriptor for zip file: /data/app/fr.my.superstuff-1.apk
W/installd(  168): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/fr.my.superstuff-1.apk' --- status=0x0100, process failed
E/installd(  168): dexopt in='/data/app/fr.my.superstuff-1.apk' out='/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@fr.my.superstuff-1.apk@classes.dex' res=256
W/PackageManager(  929): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/fr.my.superstuff-1.apk
D/AndroidRuntime( 3204): Shutting down VM
E/WifiController(  929): Not handled here 155652
```

I tried after that to navigate with `adb shell su` through the directories but I guess all the files written in the logcat are temporary because I couldn't find them.
Here is my Makefile :

```
MAIN_ACTIVITY=fr.my.superstuff/.$(shell grep "<activity android:name" AndroidManifest.xml | cut -d\" -f2)
SDK_PATH=/people/me/Documents/Android/sdk
NDK_PATH=/people/me/Documents/Android/android-ndk-r10e

APP_TAG=ARViewer
LOG_FILTER=$(APP_TAG):V NativeApp:V VES:V AndroidRuntime:E libEGL:W StrictMode:V libc:F DEBUG:I

all: compile-debug

compile-debug:
    +$(NDK_PATH)/ndk-build -j NDK_DEBUG=1
    cp thirdparty/TangoSDK_Gemma_Java.jar libs/ 
    cp thirdparty/QCAR/libs/armeabi-v7a/libQCAR.so libs/armeabi-v7a/
    cp thirdparty/QCAR/libs/QCAR-hacked.jar libs/
    ant -Djava.compilerargs=-Xlint debug installd

# compile-release:
#   LC_ALL= $(NDK_PATH)/ndk-build -j NDK_DEBUG=0
#   ant release installr

# fast-compile-debug:
#   @/bin/zsh -c 'echo > /tmp/.ant-input && echo > /tmp/.ant-output && \
#       echo fast-compile-debug >> /tmp/.ant-input && \
#       ( while IFS='' read -r line; do echo "$$line"; \
#       [[ "$$line" =~ "^ant>" ]] && exit; done \
#       < <(tailf /tmp/.ant-output)) | strings'

clean:
    ant clean
    rm -rf obj libs

test:
    @urxvt -e sh -c "adb logcat -c; adb shell am start -n $(MAIN_ACTIVITY); adb logcat -s $(LOG_FILTER)"

debug-java:
    adb shell am start -e debug true -n $(MAIN_ACTIVITY)
    adb forward tcp:7777 jdwp:$$(adb jdwp | tail -1)
    jdb -sourcepath src -attach localhost:7777

debug-native:
    adb shell am start -e debug true -n $(MAIN_ACTIVITY)
    $(NDK_PATH)/ndk-gdb

log:
    adb logcat -s $(LOG_FILTER)
```

I have no idea how to solve this error. i saw other stack threads but it didn't help me. I'm not using Android studio nor any editor, I was given this code just to install it and after that work around.

**EDIT :** After some searches I found that it may have something to do with dex files, as said in the logcat. The tablet uses Android 4.4.2 and dex is 038, but I can't find if they are compatible between each other.
But it should work, as it worked before on the same tablet but different computer. Same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
It was a version problem : the tablet is running Android 4.4 KitKat, on the computer I installed SDK 26, but KitKat runs with SDK 19, which can be downloaded with sdkmanager. However then I was missing the ant folder, so I downloaded it, however it doesn't come with the ant build.xml file. So I took it savagely from SDK 25 (links here [The ant/ folder is suddenly missing from Android SDK. Did Google remove it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912824/the-ant-folder-is-suddenly-missing-from-android-sdk-did-google-remove-it) ). 
Now it installs !